# Error when implementing expansion panel in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make an expansion panel in my Android app but I tried many libraries and all of them can't sync in my Android Studio.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

    compile 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is what happens after sync:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
>   Install Repository and sync project
> Open File
> Show in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 0):

You should change

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'

to

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

which is the latest available version found here

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project level gradle inside allprojects -> repositories

```
Add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

Comment: thanks it compile successfully but an error it privew layout in xml

Comment: that you can resolve the selecting the app theme in preview option. check at the top of the preview window. Also, upvote this answer.